# How to format to other number bases besides decimal, hexadecimal?

Tags: rust

I need to format (for example 6) to base 3 output (it will be 20). All I found was writing the conversion manually or using another libraries.

```
let a = (format!("{:b}",n));
```

or

```
let a = (format!("{:x}",n));
```

convert to bin and hex, but I need another base.

Comment: Why would Rust put base 3 in the core library? This is a job for a crate.

Comment: Javascript allows `number.toString(base)` and Rust does have [`from_str_radix`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i8.html#method.from_str_radix) so I could see why this expectation exists.

Comment: But yeah, I think you'll need to implement this manually.

Comment: half a year ago I was programming in js,so i thought there is something like number.toString(base) :(